THINGSBOARD: How to modify (simple math) a value before I show it in a dashboard
I just landed into the thingsboard world, and so far I've been able to integrate it with our Chirpstack server and show a very basic dashboard with the received telemetry. All good for now, but I foresee a very complete (and complex!) tool I will have to slowly learn.
Our first necesity is we are sending a value which is a 4-20mA value from a pH sensor, and we need to transform it into a 0-14 value. So far it already shows a bar with the original value in the range 4-20.
How can I add a simple math expresion (ma-4)/16*14 to show real pH values? Does it involve rule chains? I have tried to understand them but they seem complex...hopefully there's a way to do so without them, or there a very simple way involving them....
Thanks in advance!!

It's actually very simple to do, it doesn't invilve rule chain modifications.
You can use post processing function of your widget:
https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/widgets/#:~:text=The%20data%20post%2Dprocessing%20function,function%20in%20the%20field%20below.
return (value-4)/16*14;


AWESOME!! I didn't see this option! It fits perfectly my needs!! And simple, yeah!! Thanks a lot!!

Ok I did his and now am having a rare problem with the post processing in all my widgets. Can anyone take a look at this post please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78928350/thingsboard-widget-post-processing-for-data-series-gets-ignored-after-next-tele
