Thingsboard Widget. Post-processing for data series gets ignored after next telemetry received
Environment. Thingsboard CE on home server running Ubuntu
Taking data from Chirpstack v4.0 server
I created a dashboard for our client, to show water flow counter (3x) values. I used the widget BARS.
I added 3 data series for 3 different parameters in one device, each parameter containig 1 of the 3 counters (pulses)
As the mechanical counters they are attached to, have been rolling for years, I needed to sync the counting to the mechanical devices, so I enabled "use data post processing" for each parameter, and entered like "return value+32545;", so this would make this counter start at 32545 and so on.
This worked great for over a month until today when I was touching stuff somewhere to solve a different problem, that suddenly this bar widget starts to show the basic counters, with no added value, as if I had removed the "+ 32545" in the formula. Actually when I refresh the page (F5) it shows fine (32585) but after a while, the widget reloads itself with the wrong values (without +32545), and will stay like that until I reload the page again. I realized that it fails right as soon as the next telemetry data is received (each minute, second 09). So I refresh, it shows 36472 for instance, and then next minute 09 seconds it turns to 17 for instance



How can I fix this?
Thanks in advance!
Thanks
